# Sign / Verify with nodejs crypto always false

Tags: node.js

I need to sign and verify messages in `node.js`. I followed the `crypto` package [document](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_verify) but I always get a `false` on the verify method, which indicates that the signature is incorrect.

The `RSA` `public key` and `private key` I'm using are working well for encrypt / decrypt messages with the same `crypto` package.

Here's the code:

```
var crypto = require("crypto");
var eol = require('os').EOL;
```

The sign and verify methods:

```
function RSASign(privateKey, data) {
    const sign = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256');
    sign.update(data);
    var sig = sign.sign(privateKey, 'hex')
    console.log(sig);
    return sig;
}

function RSAVerify(publicKey, signature, data) {
    const verify = crypto.createVerify('RSA-SHA256');
    verify.update(data);
    console.log(verify.verify(publicKey, signature));
}
```

I'm calling the methods using

```
var dataToSign = "some data";
var sig = RSASign(privateKey, dataToSign);
RSAVerify(publicKey, sig, dataToSign);
```

The public key:

```
var pubStr = 'MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCbbBSVpWzSmCGVeezhuVFgUEYowUxgX/SnFdymGRCHGc77d5I0xkMAnIOWbI2MmP8j/7sdfPuUF0V5zw+Hd/7iZ6vs2k4JRKdprrB/zSC4GGqCDpDkbRYydcw3kwDgKkHhDp6NwIKvvl87WsnFozi487tGPQ8NO15hngwsV7DrawIDAQAB';
var publickKey = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----' + eol + pubStr + eol + '-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';
```

The private key:

```
var p = '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';
var privateKey = '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----' + eol + p + eol + '-----END PRIVATE KEY-----'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While verifying `verify.verify(publicKey, signature,'hex')`,you have to include the signatureEncoding that you have used during encoding

[verify signature](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_verify_verify_object_signature_signatureencoding)

```
 function RSAVerify(publicKey, signature, data) {
        const verify = crypto.createVerify('RSA-SHA256');
        verify.update(data);
        console.log(verify.verify(publicKey, signature,'hex'));
    }
```

Comment: Or remove the `output encoding` from `sign.sign()`.

Comment: yes..if signatureEncoding is not provided,it will be utf8 by default